# null vs undefined in parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse for storing facebook profile pictures of users.. now in my MainActivity

```
ParseFile file=ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getParseFile("profilePic");
if(file==null)
{ get Photo from Facebook And Store it in Parse();
}
```

Now my problem is initially it is undefined in parse internet browser interface and then this code executes.

However, if I delete the pic from the data browser by clicking on the black cross, it changes to null rather than undefined. Then this code doesn't execute.

Comment: If you delete the file from the database, the if block isn't entered?  So that means you got a `ParseFile` back.  Perhaps `isDataAvailable` would tell you what you need to know.